# Image Overlay/Popup Zoom In and Out by Mouse Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want a functionality wherein the image opens up in an Overlay / Popup and then by the Mouse Scroll the Image Zooms In and Out.

I have tried, but the Mouse Scroll on the Overlay / Popup Image (Image Zoom In and Zoom Out) functionality is not applying.
Below is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Image Popup with Pinch to Zoom In & Out
  </title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <img class="zoomable" style='width:40%;' src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/lathrop/nebula_blue.s2014.png" />
  </p>
  
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/xz44nnc/o5lkyivqw/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('img.zoomable').css({cursor: 'pointer'}).live('click', function () {
  var img = $(this);
  var bigImg = $('<img />').css({
    'max-width': '100%',
    'max-height': '100%',
    'display': 'inline'
  });
  bigImg.attr({
    src: img.attr('src'),
    alt: img.attr('alt'),
    title: img.attr('title')
  });
  var over = $('<div />').text(' ').css({
    'height': '100%',
    'width': '100%',
    'background': 'rgba(0,0,0,.82)',
    'position': 'fixed',
    'top': 0,
    'left': 0,
    'opacity': 0.0,
    'cursor': 'pointer',
    'z-index': 9999,
    'text-align': 'center'
  }).append(bigImg).bind('click', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function () {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }).insertAfter(this).animate({
    'opacity': 1
  }, 300);
});
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using 1.3.2 jquery, are you sure?

Comment: Yes @NishargShah